# OWL/RDF Automated Planner

Tags: machine-learning, scheduling, rdf, owl, planning

Is there any software that acts as an intersection between contemporary OWL/RDF reasoners, and the older [STRIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS)-style automated planners and schedulers? Both systems make use of RETE-based pattern matching, but only the automated planners seem to formalise the concept of an "action". Unfortunately, all the projects I've found that implemented automated planning, like [Graphplan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphplan) or [SOAR](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/soar/home), seem to be dead or dying, and never seemed to scale well to begin with. Current data stores are implemented on RDMS and can scale to and reason over millions of triples, but I haven't found any that specifically try and reason over actions. I can envision how the concept of actions might be represented in traditional RDF, but I'm sure it would still be very complicated and hackish without official support. Unfortunately, I can't find much prior art. Has this been done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java, ASL) sits on top of the RETE based rule engine [Drools Expert](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert) and formalizes the concept of a `Move`, which might or might not be the *action* you're looking for. It excels at scaling out, both in data as in planning constraints. And it's production ready and has a complete reference manual.

There is some research going on to do *OWL* with Drools Expert, but I don't know how far that is at this point.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently looking into Planner. It's certainly usable, actively maintained, and open source, although I'm not sure how scalable it is. It defines all it's domain logic in compiled Java objects, and encodes the problem specification in domain-specific XML files. In other words, you can't update the domain or problem by "uploading" an OWL/RDF file into a database. You'd have to translate your data into the domain-specific XML and/or manually write Java code and recompile, which seems impractical. I hope I'm wrong about this.

Comment: "I'm not sure how scalable it is." It excels at scaling out, both in data (=search space) as in constraints. The only thing I 've seen that can scale to a similar size out there, is cpsolver, but that's a research prototype (and no longer actively maintained IIRC).

Comment: "it encodes the problem specification in domain-specific XML files." No, it does not. That's just because I don't want to burden the examples with a database connection, yet I need test data. The whole thing is build to be able to work on plain old java objects and it's up to you where you get them from (database, xml, infinispan, webservice, ...)